# Create custom projection for Shapefile, given specific target coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, proj, proj4js, reprojection-mathematics

I have a somewhat odd situtaion. A client has provided me with a Shapefile that has no projection information, along with an image of the map that it corresponds to. I have run some coordinates through [WhatTheProj](https://stevage.github.io/WhatTheProj/) and it matches no known EPSG code.

So, my next thought is to somehow create a projection that maps coordinates correctly. I know how to create a Proj4 string and test whether it's right, but I don't actually know anything about projections or how to go about this. Are there any tools that would help?